# Add discount rule name in sales order

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, sales-order

I want to add discount rule with coupon code in order total section in sales order in admin-end.
[image: order discount]

Please let me know where I can make modifications. Sorry I just forgot to tell that coupon are getting generated dynamically via extension, actually the coupon code is being generated by abandoned cart extension.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module. Please contact them directly for support.

Comment: @DavidManners - Yes, you are right overall question is litle off topic but I didn't deleted it because I thought answer posted by Marius is quite usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a discount rule you are able to fill in some labels.
Check the `Labels` tab on the add/edit screen.

[image: labels]
If you have a label set it will be used in the discount line in the totals.

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to tell that coupon are getting generated dynamically via extension, actually the coupon code is being generated by abandoned cart extension.

Comment: Then maybe you should contact the developer for this.

Comment: Hi Marius, Can you let me know which file is generating  or displaying discount here. I have enabled template hints for admin, but didn't find exactly which template file or block file is it.

Comment: Must be something related to order totals. I don't know the exact file